# How to write a function that takes a parameter that is used only if a macro is turned on

Tags: c++, macros

I have a function that takes a parameter but that parameter is only used if a certain macro is turned on. e.g.,

```
void function(bool parameter_for_debug, ....some other parameters used with or without debug turned on....) {
  // do some stuff with other parameters

#ifdef DEBUG
  // do stuff with parameter_for_debug
#endif

}
```

The problem with this function is you get the `unused parameter` warning when compiling with `DEBUG` off.

The current solution I have is to just instead of writing a single `function`, write `function_without_debug` and `function_with_debug` where the former doesn't contain `parameter_for_debug` and the debug logic, and the latter does (with the macro flags removed). Then in the calling function, I do

```
#ifdef DEBUG
  function_with_debug(....)
#else
  function_without_debug(....)
#endif
```

Is there another way to approach this problem? I feel there should be. The problem with my approach is just having some overlap in the two functions.

Comment: `[[maybe_unused]]` or old school `(void)parameter_for_debug;`

Comment: @Eljay Could you expand on the former `[[maybe_unused]]`? I'm not sure what you mean by that. For the latter, I think you just mean including `(void)parameter_for_debug;` in the body of the function to silence the warning

Comment: [`[[maybe_unused]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused) was added C++17.  For the `void` cast, your understanding is correct.